# codename one, browser component

Tags: browser, codenameone

Has anyone using codenameone experienced a challenge in displaying local or external webpage on device? On emulator it works fine but on device it just does display. Below is a sample of what am using:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi Browser World");
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi Am a browser"));

    browser = new BrowserComponent();
    cnt_browser = new Container();
    cnt_browser.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cnt_browser.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);

    browser.setURL("http://imediakenya.com");

    hi.addComponent(cnt_browser);
    hi.show();
```

Any pointer will be greatly appreciated. Am testing using a Samsung SGH-T599N.

Thanks,
Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

Apparently, the browser component has to be placed using a layout manager. Same case is for the local html file. For local html file it loaded but much
slower or after restarting the app.

```
    Form fm_brw = new Form("Hi Browser World");
    fm_brw.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setURL("http://google.com");

    fm_brw.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
    fm_brw.show();
```

Comment: **What is the correct way to display a HTML file downloaded and saved in the file system?** 

1. I am able to download and save in the .cn1 folder on Simulator but it doesn't display. I tested using the Page.html sample file found in the old Kitchen Sink demo.

Comment: This what I hve done so far! Can I use absolute paths like file:///storage/emulated/0/Folder/Page.html instead? 

`Form fm_brw = new Form(); fm_brw.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` `FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();` `fs.mkdir(fs.getAppHomePath() + "SampleFolder");` 

`Util.downloadUrlToFile("http://somesite.com/Page.html", fs.getAppHomePath() + "SampleFolder/Page.html", true);` 

`BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();` `browser.setURL(fs.getAppHomePath() + "SampleFolder/Page.html);` 

fm_brw.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser); 
fm_brw.show();